# IE webpage you are viewing is trying to close the window message

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, tabs, warnings

I have 3 webpages. They use the same ascx. I have a button on ascx called "send message". When I click that out of 3 pages 2 pages close up without the message. The other one shows up this warning. There is nothing majorly different in 3 pages except the properties I pass to ascx. When I test in chrome,firefox and safari the 3 pages close without warning . On IE 2 close without warning and 1 shows up warning. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind found the solution.

```
   function closeWindow() {
        window.open('', '_self', ''); //added this line and it worked
        window.close();
    }
```

It now closes after sending message without the warning message